# SecretsManagerClient timeout when runing locally using lambda-local

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am using below code to retrieve from Secrets Manager. This is timingout when run locally  using **lambda-local**

```
let response = await client.send(
          new GetSecretValueCommand({
            SecretId: secret_name,
            VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT", // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified
          })
        );
        dbSecretString = response.SecretString;
      } catch (error) {
        // For a list of exceptions thrown, see
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
        throw error;
      }
```

Does anyone faced similar issue ?